# FireDac and aborting a before post, with system.abort

Tags: delphi, exception, firedac

In continue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838546/delphi-canceling-a-tdataset-post-in-an-onbeforepost-event),when using FireDac, and calling in BeforePost event to a function that calls, Abort, cause a full system abort that breaks the loop that running around that abort.

```
while not fdOtherQuery.eof do begin
  fdQuery.insert;
  fdquery.fields[0].asstring := fdOtherQuery.fields[0].asstring;
  fdquery.post;
fdOtherQuery.next;
end;
```

Before post:

```
procedure TForm1.AzureDayarKriaAdditionsBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  calculcation;  
end;

procedure calculaction;
begin
  if fdQuery.fields[0].asstring = 0 then abort;
end;
```

In case the abort in calculation is called, then the

> while not fdOtherQuery.eof do begin

is also stoped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abort raises a silent exception, which can be caught with try ... except.

```
while not fdOtherQuery.eof do begin
  fdQuery.insert;
  fdquery.fields[0].asstring := fdOtherQuery.fields[0].asstring;
  try
    fdquery.post;
  except
    on E: EAbort do
    begin
      // log the error (when needed)
    end;
  end;   
  fdOtherQuery.next;
end;
```